# How to make cursor pointer on mouse hover only on a particular column in Datatable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have looked in vain and do not really know the CSS rules for doing what I've described. I have tried:

```
 $("#tblUserList tbody tr td:eq(1)").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

But it does not work. I have tried many different variations without success. Any idea how to do this? I want to show the particular column as clickable with the hand cursor.

Table looks like this:

```
 <table id="tblUserList" style="font-size:x-small;display:none">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>M</th>
                <th>Last</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Direct</th>
                <th>Dept</th>
                <th>Service</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

And I load it up with this:

```
  $("#tblUserList").dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetAllActiveUsers")',
        bJQueryUI: true,
        sProcessing: "<img src='~/Images/spinner.gif' />",
        dom: 'T<"clear">rti',
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "10%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "1%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "10%", sClass: "smallfonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
            { "sWidth": "8%", sClass: "smallFonts" },
        ]
    })

 $("#tblUserList").dataTable().fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
```

And then capture the click with:

```
 $('#tblUserList tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        var visIdx = $(this).index();
        if (visIdx != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        var par = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        var oTable = $("#tblUserList").dataTable();
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
        var name = aData[0];
        if (name != '') {
            GetUserDetails(name, 'user');
        }
        else {
            $("#lblError").html("The User ID is blank in that row.");
            $("#MessageDialog").dialog({ title: "No User ID" });
            $("#MessageDialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have the html code of your `#tblUserList`? What are the different variations you have tried?

Comment: @Martin I've added some details to the question.

Comment: pure CSS will do this for you. Answer below.

Answer (score 2):

**If you're trying to select the th then replace `td` with `th`**

This should work for you. If you're just trying to select just the first `td`

```css
table tr td:first-of-type {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you're trying to select another td then you can use `:nth-of-type()`

```css
table tr td:nth-of-type(3) { /* Select the 3rd td */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
    <td>No speeches. Short speech.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace x with the column you want to add style too

```
table tr td:nth-child(x):hover,
table tr th:nth-child(x):hover
{cursor:pointer}
```